# How is an encrypted PDF document encrypted by both user and owner password?

Tags: pdf, encryption

When I encrypt a PDF document providing **both** a user and an owner password, I can open the document using either of those passwords.

As far as I understand, modern PDF encryption uses AES128/256 which works with one key (password).

Is the document duplicated internally and each copy encrypted with a password? Having two encrypted documents inside the file was not apparent from the encrypted document file size.

*PD: I know the "user experience" differences between user and owner passwords in PDF.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, in cases like this, a "master key" is randomly created and used to encrypt.  For each key that will actually be used to access the document, we encrypt the master key with that user or owner key.  The results of these (small) encryption operations are included in the file directly (e.g. multiple copies of the encrypted *master key*, not document).

Thus, to decrypt the file, we need the master key, and to get the master key, we can provide either the "user" or "owner" key and use that key to decrypt one of the master key ciphertexts.

Comment: Thanks! Is this how it is done in the PDF or is an example of how it may be done?

Comment: It is, more or less, done like this for PDFs.  Simplified though obviously!

Comment: The main simplification here is that in case of the older (ISO 32000-1) PDF encryption schemes, the user password itself was the master key, and for owner access the PDF contained the user password encrypted using the owner password. As a consequence, someone knowing the owner password can retrieve the user password! The newer (ISO 32000-2) encryption scheme uses an architecture more like the one described in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are **not** two different encrypted copies of the document within a single PDF.

The user password strictly is used to limit the ability to **open** a document.

The **master** password controls the permissions of a document. E.g. Document Assembly not being permitted or Form Filling not being allowed.  A master password can **also** be used to open a PDF in place of a user password.

The *type* of encryption used doesn't depend on if there is only a master password or both a user and master password.